# Can the police allow someone to look around my property for anything stolen?

Tags: criminal-law, search-and-seizure

I was cleaning a property when the police rolled up, said I wasn't supposed to be there.so they got a warrant for my place and allowed a man from the property to come and walk around my place to see what was from the property. This man was not the owner of the property I was cleaning.

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: Why do you think they needed the *owner* to identify stolen goods? To identify a diamond necklace, I would assume the store clerk that sells it is the best option to identify it, not the corporate owner who maybe isn't even a real person.

Comment: Did this man search the property by himself, or was he accompanied by police officers?

Answer (score 2):

The jurisdiction matters; in the US, a search warrant must generally be carried out by law enforcement personnel, and should specify what is being looked for.  This would not allow non-law enforcement personnel to enter the property to "look for stuff."

The search warrant and search warrant application to the judge should specify the probable cause and what is being searched for specifically.  Without seeing both it would be hard to know if either were done properly.  False statements made to apply for a warrant may be a criminal or civil issue.

You would really need a lawyer in the local jurisdiction who knows the specific laws there and what recourse would be, but I suspect you could sue for trespass (if that is allowed in your jurisdiction) for the non law-enforcement person who entered your property.

Comment: Could law enforcement personnel allow a civilian to accompany them as they search the property, e.g. to identify potentially stolen property?

Comment: @NateEldredge NAL, but typically no. There may be exceptions depending upon jurisdiction and maybe special circumstances.  Often times warrants specify not only what is to be searched but what they are expecting to find.  An exception to this, but kind of the opposite, is when a civilian is appointed by the judge to limit a search.  This might occur if a lawyer's office is to be searched and the rights of the clients, not in question, are to be protected.